# Punctuation of eye dialect 

Tags: punctuation, eye-dialect

Suppose you have a sentence which concludes with the eye dialect *somethin'* for the word *something*.  Where does the period go?  Which is correct?

> This is really somethin'.
>
> This is really somethin.'

It seems to me that the apostrophe is part of the word, and hence attaches to it as opposed to the sentence.  Thus, I'd put the period after the apostrophe.  The second construction looks like an error, with mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 7):

You're correct—the apostrophe is there to signify that a letter (or letters) were omitted from the word, and so, the apostrophe goes with the word and before the period.

While periods go inside quotes in American English, this isn't a quote.

Comment: I think that the period goes inside whenever, isn't that true? Not just quotes; it has/had something to do with printing press technology... typography, see below. I don't think it has anything to do with just quotes. I think. :)

Comment: @kalaracey - no, that would not be correct. Some useful references: [\[1\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Typographical_considerations), [\[2\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Apostrophe_showing_omission), [\[3\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Punctuation_styles_when_quoting) (yes, those are from Wikipedia, but they appear to be solid on this topic).

Answer (score 3):

Place the apostrophe before the period in this case.